# Rest Jersey does not consume POST Request Payload JSON object

Tags: java, json, rest

This is my ajax code, here I send json object as Request payload.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
       var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
       var address = $("#address").val();
       $("#studentInsert").click(function() {
           student.presonal_details = {
               firstName: $("#firstName").val(),
               lastName: $("#lastName").val(),
               address: $("#address").val(),
           }

           $.ajax({
               type: "post",
               url: "http://localhost:8080/RestJersey/rest/jsonRequestReceiver/saveStudentDeta il",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               data: JSON.stringify(student.presonal_details),
               success: function(data) {
                   console.log(data);
               }
           });
       });
   });
```

Java Code:

I want to know how do I write REST service API code for receiving the json Object.

```
@POST
@Path("/saveStudentDetail")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void saveStudentDetail() {
}
```

This is my `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>RestJersey</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <!-- <welcome-file>index1.html</welcome-file> -->
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And may POJO class:

```
package com.rest.test.to;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class StudentDetailsTO {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use below code

  ```
  @POST
  @Path("/saveStudentDetail")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void saveStudentDetail(StudentDetailsTO student){
        String fname= student.getFirstName();
        String lname= student.getLastName();
        String address= student.getAddress();
      }
  ```